# != keeps automatically changing to ≠

Tags: kali-linux

Every time I type != in mousepad & in my terminal it keeps automatically changing to ≠. I am using the latest version of Kali Linux.

Can anyone help me switch this off please?

Chris

Comment: What terminal do you use?

Comment: Hi Henrik,

I use the Terminal Emulator.

Chris

Comment: This is likely due to the terminal supporting displaying particular digraphs, together with a font (like Fira Code) that has these digraph characters. There should be a font setting in the terminal where this can be disabled. As I don't currently run Kali Linux and don't know what terminal Kali uses, I can't give a full answer.

Comment: Why the down votes? is it because the OP dared to mention Kali?

Comment: @Henriksupportsthecommunity why would that matter?  The OP said this also happens in mousepad.

Comment: Because many terminal (emulators) exist, and I thought complete information might help somebody.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like the ligatures are displayed in the terminal emulator. Try using the code below in your `~/.config/fontconfig/fonts.conf` file.

```
<?xml version='1.0'?>
<!DOCTYPE fontconfig SYSTEM 'fonts.dtd'>
<fontconfig>
  <match>
    <match target="font">
    <test name="family" compare="eq" ignore-blanks="true">
      <string>YOUR_FONT_HERE</string>
    </test>
    <edit name="fontfeatures" mode="append">
      <string>liga off</string>
      <string>dlig off</string>
    </edit>
  </match>
</fontconfig>
```